# Is there a way to recursively delete only empty subdirectories?

Tags: python

I have  use case where I want to delete only empty subdirectories in python given the state directories.
I have evaluated the below approaches

**1. find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir{}**

**2. os.walkdir/scandir and do rmdir**

Is there a better faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Using `os.walk()` and `os.rmdir()` should be as fast as you can get with Python.

Comment: U would use the bash command if you don't need to support windows because it's much better understandable and shorter

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to automate the process of removing empty dirs using python, you can try this,**

```
import os
import errno

source = "path_to_souce_dir" #-----> source dir path

def delete(source):
    for filename in os.listdir(source):
        fullpath = os.path.join(source, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
            try:
                os.rmdir(fullpath)
            except OSError as ex:
                if ex.errno == errno.ENOTEMPTY:
                    delete(fullpath)

delete(source)
```

Comment: This will not work recursively, as OP's examples do.

Comment: @AKX I have tried executing the code, the above code produces exact same result as executing  `find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir{}`. What do you think?

Comment: I must have missed the recursive `delete(fullpath)` call the last time around, sorry. That said, this should probably use `if os.path.isdir(...)`, since device files, symlinks and other things do exist :)

Comment: @AKX Its okay, replaced `os.path.isfile` with `os.path.isdir`. Thanks for suggestion.